# .kt files not recognized in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, ide

I opened my Studio today and Android Studio didn't recognize Kotlin files. `.kt` files started showing up as just an ordinary file. I checked my Plugins and I still have the Kotlin plugin. I tried uninstalling and installing it again. But no use.

I tried building my building my project from Terminal and it works fine. But Android studio doesn't understand Kotlin files.

---

Configuration:

Android Studio 3.1

Kotlin 1.2.41

OS: MacOS Sierra

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to `Library/Preferences` and delete the `AndroidStudio3.1` folder. This is the config directory for my Android Studio.

Once deleted, I started Studio again, and the config was created fresh. Now everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

**Update Kotlin plugin**:

Go to

```
menu
preferences
plugins
find Kotlin plugin
update
```

Comment: Thanks. Was using 3.3 canary 5 when this happened.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say, I'm creating new file named `HomeFragment`, and `AndroidStudio` didn't recognize it as `kotlin file`. Fix Steps:

1. AndroidStudio -> Preferences -> Editor -> File Types
2. Click on `File type auto-detected by file content`, make sure this sections `doesn't have` prefill `File name patterns` - `HomeFragment`, if it does, delete it.
3. Click on `Kotlin`, make sure `it has` "*.kt"
4. Click on `Text`, make sure it `doesnt have` "*.kt"

once done, click `Apply` and `OK`

[image: Step 2]
[image: Step 3]
[image: Step 4]

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem too, after upgrading my Android Studio from 3.1.4 to 3.2.1

And I have followed @[Evgenii Vorobei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7212836/evgenii-vorobei) step, found no "Update" button available just install and uninstall.

So I go to the root project `build.gradle` file update the `kotlin_version` from `1.3.11` to `1.3.21`, sync project then restart Android studio

This is work for me

[image]

Update:

You also can update the plugin with `Tools > Kotlin > Configure kotlin plugin update`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I already had kotlin configured and could see the files in the "Project" view but could not see them in the "Android" view.  When in "Android" mode, if you can see the File->new->Kotlin File/Class in the File Menu, create a new Kotlin file.  When I did this, the new file appeared in the menu along with the other file I had copied in place.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the similar issue, but in my case it was due to misc.xml file.
Android studio had added below line in misc.xml file

```
<component name="ProjectPlainTextFileTypeManager">
    <file url="paht_to_file_not_being_recognized" />
</component>
```

after removing this line, everything worked perfectly. If you refactor -> rename file but then also the issue persist, this can be a possible reason.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when accidentally `.kt` file type association was moved to Text file from Kotlin.

To fix this remove `*.kt` from Text and add under Kotlin (if not present)

More info on it from [jetbrains issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-255081/.kt-file-not-recognized)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried File -> Settings -> Editor -> File Types as both Gideon Steven and AppDeveloper showed here but it didn't work. It was when I did:

1. File -> File Properties -> Associate with file type
2. File pattern: *.kt
3. Selected Kotlin

it started working for me again. But without your tips I wouldn't have come up with this. So, Thanks!